# SOAPElementImpl has not setTextContent method

Tags: weblogic-10.x

Strange error in weblogic 10.3.3:

I'm running a SpringIntegration system on weblogic 10.3.3. My problem is that my Node gets the type weblogic.xml.saaj.SOAPElementImpl under runtime and that the method setTextContent fails with "UNIMPLEMENTED" when I run my services from SOAPUi. I added this to the startWeblogic.cmd file to get it to run with apache implementation instead of weblogic but doesn't seem to help: 
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConnectionImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.MessageFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.MessageFactoryImpl -Djavax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory=org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPFactoryImpl

Anyone experienced this?

Answer (score 1):

I changed my implementation from `SOAPElement.setTextContent()` to `SOAPElement.setValue()`. That seems to have done the trick.